# How can I translate sqlite tables data to regional language such as hindi or marathi?

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite, localization

I created a windows app in WPF which uses SQLite database table to show some results based on input.

Here is the snapshot of the data:

[The table Data Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GWNGA.png)

There are around 30 columns in this table. I translated the data in Hindi language manually and saved them as Unicode.

Is there a way to translate this English data to Marathi and other languages and save it in the database with a different table name using any API?

Comment: as far as i know, there is none,translation in WPF is done manually via static or dynamic resource files. you can consider using angular, it has a package called i18n

Comment: I would say this has nothing to do with C#, Wpf or Sqlite. There are transplation API:s from both Google and Microsoft (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/translator/business/translator-api/) that you can use.